# I installed tensorflow and tensorflow_gpu on my Windows 10 64-bit OS with PyCharm and Python 3.7.2. But i get these errors while using tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pycharm, python-3.7

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\sai
>   kushal\PycharmProjects\live\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\sai
>   kushal\PycharmProjects\live\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\sai
>   kushal\PycharmProjects\live\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File "C:\Users\sai
>   kushal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242,
>   in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\Users\sai kushal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342,
>   in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/sai
>   kushal/PycharmProjects/live/testing_2.py", line 1, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf   File "C:\Users\sai kushal\PycharmProjects\live\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import   File "C:\Users\sai
>   kushal\PycharmProjects\live\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Users\sai
>   kushal\PycharmProjects\live\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\sai
>   kushal\PycharmProjects\live\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Users\sai
>   kushal\PycharmProjects\live\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Users\sai
>   kushal\PycharmProjects\live\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File "C:\Users\sai
>   kushal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242,
>   in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "C:\Users\sai kushal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342,
>   in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common reasons
>   and solutions. Include the entire stack trace above this error message
>   when asking for help.

Comment: Did you check the link provided?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.7 doesn't support tensorflow yet, use python 3.6 Instead, that should fix this error, if it doesn't, comment below.